# Bleeding Edge Non-elementary OS Packages

Tags: package-management

I want to install the latest Konsole on elementary OS. I'm considering adding debian sid to the sources, but I'm not exactly sure how I should go through with this.

Answer (score 2):

Do not add Debian sid to the sources as this will overwrite all the Freya / Ubuntu packages with Debian sid ones and will break your system.You might be able to find a PPA somewhere though

Comment: Would Kubuntu's PPA work? https://community.kde.org/Kubuntu/PPAs#Kubuntu.27s_PPA_Repositories

Comment: I do not have a virtual machine to test.I will try later